# Generating a dynamic ARP Request in C?

Tags: networking, routes, arp

Having simulated a router, it's important that it should be able to generate an ARP Request and respond to the same. I do not understand how to begin implementing the same?
Are there an API's that exist in C that generate ARP Request.

Suppose I have a route lookup in my simulated router and I find out that, the route exists but  there is no static ARP entry, the process should be able to generate an ARP Request.
Do I need a tap interface for this sort of functionality?

Answer (score 0):

I believe to answer your question, knowledge of the environment is needed. What OS is your simulator running in? Unix, Linux, Windows, OS X? And you are developing router software for which hardware (or chipset or embedded software, real-time operating system?)

If you are simulating your hardware router software in an OS like windows, there are utilities and commands that you can have your sandboxed simulator environment issue that can be intercepted by your simulated router.

Bottom line, a little more knowledge of the environment of your simulator might help! Good luck :)